# Django Error: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, django, formset

Getting this error. How do I change the POST formset data to ensure the image actually gets saved?

TypeError at /photos/add_photos/
 string indices must be integers, not str
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   /photos/add_photos/
 Django Version:    1.6.5
 Exception Type:    TypeError
 Exception Value:
 string indices must be integers, not str

```
@login_required
    def addimage(request):
        user = request.user
        blogposts = Blogpost.objects.filter(user=user)
        imageformset = formset_factory(Image, AddImageForm,extra=1)
        if request.method == "POST":
            formset = imageformset(request.POST, request.FILES)
            print formset
            if formset.is_valid() :
                for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                        image = form['image']
                        title = form['title']
                        blogpost = form['blogpost']
                        description = form['description']
                        photo = Image(
                            title = title,
                            image= image,
                            blogpost=blogpost,
                            description=description,
                            )
                        photo.user = request.user
                        photo.save()

                        messages.success(request, 'We did it. Pictures are on the interwebs!')
                        return HttpResponseRedirect("/%s/%s/" % (user, blogpost.slug))
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Oh no! Something went wrong. Try again.')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/photos/add_photos/')

        else:
            formset = imageformset()
            formset.fields['blogpost'].queryset = Blogpost.objects.filter(user=user)

        return render_to_response('photos/add_photos.html', {
            'formset' : formset,
            'blogpost' : blogposts,
            },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this line:

```
for form in formset.cleaned_data:
```

What you actually need to do is iterate through `formset.forms`, then for each form access the `cleaned_data`:

```
for form in formset:
    image = form.cleaned_data['image']
    ..etc...
```